# Why is stack size almost always 132KiB on a Linux machine?

Tags: c, linux

The following command computes size of the stack for each running process on a Linux machine.

```
# find /proc -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '/proc/[0-9]*' -exec cat '{}'/maps \; | grep stack | cut -d' ' -f1 | gawk --non-decimal-data 'BEGIN{FS="-"} {printf "%d\n", (("0x" $2) - ("0x" $1))/1024}' | sort
```

In almost all the cases size of the stack is 132KiB. Why is this number so special? Is this the minimum possible size of the stack?

Comment: It's probably the minimum for C and C++ programs compiled with GCC, which means the majority of Linux programs. The reason that few programs exceed it is then that, in well-written C and C++ programs, call stacks aren't very deep, recursion isn't extensively used and non-trivial objects are allocated on the free store.

Comment: As long as the number of running processes isn't so great that you exceed the maximum command line size, you can simply do `cat /proc/*/maps | grep ...`

Comment: Related, see [Qualys Security Advisory - The Stack Clash](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/19/1) on OSS-Security mailing list. Its shows off some neat tricks, and its pretty damning of the guard page. Its amazing how many OS'es they took down with it.

Comment: pidstat -s -l -p ALL  # show all process with stack size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel sets new process stacks to 128kB in [`setup_arg_pages()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0/fs/exec.c#L738):

```
stack_expand = 131072UL; /* randomly 32*4k (or 2*64k) pages */
```

When you add a single 4kB guard page, that comes to 132kB.  If the process has never used more than this much stack, it won't have been expanded past this size.

Comment: What does randomly means in this case?

Comment: "randomly" in this case means the value was chosen solely because a value was needed and not due to any kind of study to determine what would be the best initial value.  The original programmer had no particular reason to choose that particular value.  Welcome to colloquial English as used by many programmers.